# angular ng-show "object is not a function" but still adds ng-hide class

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the html:

```
<button ng-show="finalize == 'Finalize'" ng-click="SubmitInfo('value')">Submit</button>
```

I know that there is a value finalize on the scope. I have checked with ng-inspect. It seems to be evaluating correctly because when I look at the generated source I see `class="ng-hide"`.

The problem is that on the console I see: `'TypeError: object is not a function'`. I just don't get it. When I delete the `ng-show` clause, the error goes away...

controller code:

```
    angular.element(document).ready(
fucntion () {

    $scope.finalize = $("#Finalize")[0].value;
}
    )
```

..coming from the server

Here is a fiddle, it is not working either:

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s1pm7avc/)

Comment: Add your controller code

Comment: *"When I delete the ng-hide clause, the error goes away"*. You don't even have ngHide in posted code. Anyway, add more code.

Comment: you showing ng-show code but complaining about ng-hide, please put your code to plnkr of jsfiddle

Comment: Sorry I meant ng-show, I will change the post. I have been working at this for a half hour now using ng-hide and ng-show they both give me the same error

Comment: try `ng-show="finalize && finalize == 'Finalize'"`... also side note: why aren't you using `$("#Finalize").val()`

Comment: Other side note: whatever `#Finalize` is, why aren't you using `ng-model` ?

Comment: @entropic when I put {{finalize}} next to the button it spits out the correct value. It is defined and bound...

Comment: $cyril chapon That is my way of bootstrapping it in from the server. I could of course get it via $http...but idk.

Comment: I don't get it. Can you go further ?

Comment: Also try to rename the variable to solething else. Finalize is a common word for some cleaning methods, don't play with fire

Comment: I mean that I have certain values that I know on the server before even serving up the page. So, instead of serving the page and sending back an AJAX request for them. I just populate hidden inputs in the page with these values before serving the page up. Then, I read them in my controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle was very wrong.

The module was incorrectly declared, jquery was not referenced.

Here's a plunker I added, it works:

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/N9gKVnrKNCRi9ftvyq2B?p=preview)

html:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
  <button ng-show="finalize == 'Finalize'" ng-click="SubmitInfo('value')">Submit</button>
  <button ng-show="finalize == 'All'" ng-click="SubmitInfo('value')">Another</button>
</div>

<input id="Finalize" type="hidden" value="Finalize">
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('controller', function($scope) {
        $scope.finalize = $("#Finalize")[0].value;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared the variable earlier in the controller?

```
$scope.finalize = 'Finalize';

$scope.SubmitInfo = function(value)
{
    $scope.finalize = 'nonFinalize';
};
```

Comment: `$scope.finalize = $("#Finalize")[0].value`; there is no id assigned to that element, or value.